# error: no such partition grub rescue

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-xp, ssd

I had a Windows XP on my 64GB IDE SSD. I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 using Wubi, bit it did not worked: I could choose Ubuntu from the boot menu, but it did worked. Then I installed Ubuntu 12.10 from the bootable live USB version, I choose "Install alongside Windows". After a successful installation message, I restarted the notebook and I got this error message: error: no such partition grub rescue

Things I tried without success:

http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.in/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html

UbuntuSecureRemix

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

Internet connection does not work (I have only mobile Internet access via a USB stick and it is not recognised by Boot Repair), so I cannot provide any output. I tried to save it on the pendrive, but it is not visible (or non-existent) in the other notebook I use now (Windows XP).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I had this once too - but years ago before UEFI ... there this failure-report popped up, when I forgot to make a partition table in gparted - before I build partitions on the concerning harddisk, where system is to be installed.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem. Now it is solved. Use the following process.
Just Install Ubuntu to the same drive where it was previously. It will give the GRUB menu again. Then you can be able to boot Windows and Ubuntu both. So then using Windows Format or delete the ubuntu drive BUT DON"T restart, install  MBR(similar to grub but it is for windows) then restart. It will give you a system with windows only with full space.
Shibnath